# How can I fix errors while running /opt/caspida/bin/Caspida setuphadoop during Splunk UBA installation?

Tags: hadoop, splunk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiRT0.png)
IP - 192.168.126.16
Fri Jun  2 17:06:10 +07 2023: Running: /opt/caspida/bin/Caspida setuphadoop
...............................Failed to run sudo -u  hdfs hdfs namenode -format >> /var/vcap/sys/log/caspida/caspida.out 2>&1
Fri Jun  2 17:06:11 +07 2023: [ERROR] Failed to run hadoop_setup [2]. Fix errors and re-run again.
Error in running /opt/caspida/bin/Caspida setuphadoop on 192.168.126.16.  Fix errors and re-run again.

i execute the command /opt/caspida/bin/caspida setup but stopped here hadoopsetup can't run, i don't know the cause yet. someone please help me.
I put some install logs here

Comment: Show the content of `/var/vcap/sys/log/caspida/caspida.out`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I send you files caspida.out , install.log and pre_check 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XeCwNZigFl_SadjBs2EqHgy6RNfOJUk3

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead